# What is the correct way to load the code paths of dependencies in an Erlang application.

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp, rebar

So assuming that i have an rebar app structure and in deps folder i have a number of dependencies, some are library applications and some are applications that need to be started. I usually do it like this:

```
start(_Type, _Args) ->
   code:add_path("../deps/depapp/ebin"),
   {ok, _} = application:ensure_all_started(depapp),
```

Is this the correct way to do it in an development environment ? How about in production ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you used is not necessarily a wrong way but could exposes some problems. For instance this way you have no choices for starting dependent applications which must be started before your application.

So there are other alternatives for `loading` or `starting` dependent OTP applications or libraries.

1) Using `erl` command line flags:

```
erl -pa ebin deps/*/ebing -s your_dep_app start -s your_app start
```

2) Using package manger for handling it:

As an example Rebar as a package manager can handle it for you. What you need is specifying your application dependencies in `rebar.config` and then issue `rebar get-deps` for Rebar2 or `rebar3 compile` for Rebar3. Following is a snippet of a sample config file for Rebar3:

```
{deps,[
  %% Packages
  rebar,
  {rebar,"1.0.0"},
  {rebar, {pkg, rebar_fork}}, % rebar app under a different pkg name
  {rebar, "1.0.0", {pkg, rebar_fork}},
  %% Source Dependencies
  {rebar, {git, "git://github.com/erlang/rebar3.git"}},
  {rebar, {git, "http://github.com/erlang/rebar3.git"}}]}.
```

For more information about Rebar dependency manager take a look at [this](https://www.rebar3.org/docs/dependencies) link.

Also for starting or loading them using Rebar you can make a release and let Rebar start or load them. Following is a snippet of a sample Rebar config file for making a release:

```
{relx, [
    {release, 
    {your_app, "0.1.0"},
        [your_dep_app_1,
         {your_dep_app_2, load}]}]}.
```

This config loads and starts `your_dep_app_1` but just loads `your_dep_app_2`. For more information about Rebar release manager take a look at [this](https://www.rebar3.org/docs/releases) link.